# jquery File Upload (blueimp) - IE9 doesn't support multiple file selection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload, multifile-uploader, blueimp

I'm using jquery file upload plugin per blueimp and IE9 is not allowing multiple file selection per the following code (below) or the demo:

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Can somebody provide a workaround or insight?

View:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple"/>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
    {
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), file.FileName);
            file.SaveAs(filename);
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this is a permanent issue for all versions of IE: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1173

Answer (score 0):

For Internet Explorer, you need a flash fallback, plupload does this.